# how to use @supports with background images CSS

Tags: css, mask

I'm trying to use the `mask` CSS property with `@supports` CSS at-rule and as a fallback option for older browsers I want the background image to render in it's original color.

So far I've been using this approach

```html
background-color: pink; 
background-image: url('../img/SVG/chevron-thin-right.svg'); 

@supports (-webkit-mask-image: url('../img/SVG/chevron-thin-right.svg')) and 
( -webkit-mask- size:cover) { 

-webkit-mask-image: url('../img/SVG/chevron-thin-right.svg');
-webkit-mask-size: cover; 

}
```

The problem is that the `mask` property doesn't apply correctly to the background image even if opened in a supported browser. It doesn't render the correct pink color, instead it renders a purple color(it seems like the pink is mixed with the original image color).

If I remove the `background-image: url('../img/SVG/chevron-thin-right.svg');` part from the code, then the desired pink color is rendered.

What would I need to change so the desired color renders correctly when the `mask` property is supported and the original background image is shown if it is not supported?

Comment: Well your @supports query is wrong as it also stated the *value* which isn't required. You're asking if the *property* is supported...the value is irrelevant.

Comment: So just `@supports (-webkit-mask-image)` but a demo of this *not* working would be optimal.